# iPhone XML SOAP requests or .NET Web Services

Tags: iphone, xml, soap, web-services

I've been trying to to consume SOAP requests (.NET web services) and have found some pretty good tools that I wanted to share:

1) [iPhone XML SOAP or .NET Web Services](http://grabalife.com/2009/10/19/using-net-web-services-and-dataset-objects-in-your-iphone-app/).
Really easy clean way to perform all the call needed for consuming the services.

2) [SOAP Client](http://code.google.com/p/mac-soapclient/) uses WSDL files you provide to dynamically create a graphical user interface for any given SOAP-based web service

Hopefully that will help someone as much as me!!!
Happy coding !

Answer (score -1):

If you know the xml structure that the SOAP service needs, just manually construct your HTTPRequest and POST it off.